# How to do encoding in R and why â€™ comes instead of apostrophe(')s and how to resolve it

Tags: r, encoding

Hi I am trying to do text mining in **R version 3.4.2**
I am trying to import .txt files from local drive using `VCorpus` command. 
But after Run following code

```
cname <- file.path("C:", "texts")  
cname  
dir(cname) 
library(readr)
library(tm)
docs <- VCorpus(DirSource(cname))   
summary(docs)
inspect(docs[1])
writeLines(as.character(docs[1]))
```

Output:
Well, the election, it came out really well. Next time we**â€™**ll triple the number and so on

â€™ its originally aporstophe(')s now how can i convert or get original text in **Rstudio**?

Please it will appreciate if someone help me 
Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 3):

Encoding issues are not easy to solve, since they depend on various factors (file ecnoding, encoding settings during loading, etc.). As a first step you might try the following line, if we are lucky it solves your problem.

```
Encoding(your_text) <- "UTF-8"
```

Otherwise, other solutions have to be chekced, e.g., using `stri_trans` from `stringi` package or replacing wrong symbols with brute force via `gsub(falsecharacter, desiredcharacter, fixed = TRUE)` (there are debugging tables, e.g., on [i18nqa.com](http://www.i18nqa.com/debug/utf8-debug.html)).

Comment: Thanks a lot it was encoding problem so i specifed in VCropus. But now another problem is while importing double quote comes in starting and ending of each line can you please suggest me how to remove them?

Comment: Please update your question with your new issue. Just leave the question as is and add what you get after the additional operations you have applied.

Comment: I have seen your [new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47568667/why-getting-instead-of-space-in-r-while-import-text), therefore, I guess my hint on the encoding solved your problem concerning "â€™". Therefore, please consider accepting my answer.

Answer (score 2):

I solved this a different way.

I found that apostrophes that looked like this: `'` would render properly, while ones that looked slightly different, like this: `’` would not.

So, for any text that I was printing, I converted `’` to `'` like this:

```
  mytext <- gsub("’", "'", mytext )
```

Tada... no more issues with "â€™".